# How to position nested cards in React using Material UI?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

Im using [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card) for React and working on the Material Cards Component. My requirement is, Im displaying a card which sits right below the main App bar. This card has one more smaller card nested inside it. The problem is Im able to move the smaller card inside the bigger card horizontally using the marginLeft attributes. However Im unable to move this smaller card vertically inside the bigger card. When i use marginTop attribute, the bigger(Parent card) also moves down. 
How can I change the position of the card vertically inside the parent card?

My code is as follows:

```html
<div>
  <Card style={{ width: '100vw', height: '60vh', margin: 'auto', marginTop: '0.05vh', backgroundColor: '#263238', }}>
    <Card style={{ width: '30vw', height: '40vh', marginLeft: '10vw', marginTop: '0.05vh', backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA', }}>
      <CardText color="#263238" style={{ fontSize: '3vw', }}>
        Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
      </CardText>
    </Card>
  </Card>
</div>
```

Comment: use `transform: translateX() translateY()`

Comment: ps use a snippet next time, it has a "Tidy" function to format your markup

Comment: @EmadEmami Could you please elaborate on that?